# Decoding base64 string gives a black rectangle image

Tags: php, canvas

I'm trying to get an image from canvas and save it with my php script. But when the script proceedes, I got a simple black rectangle instead of my canvas image (web-cam snapshot).
Here is my code:

```
$img = $base64Img;
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = "photo/" . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of this line:

```
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
```

Don't think it is necessary.
Otherwise all seems fine.

I usually use php `explode` to isolate the data:

```
$exploded = explode(',', $img);
$base64 = $exploded[1];
$data = base64_decode($base64);
```

But `str_replace` should also do the job.

Maybe the error is in the code that loads the image?

### UPDATE

Purpose of that line is to encode the white space in the base64 data.
This is also mentioned in [this comment on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#102113).
Probably it would be better to use the PHP function `urlencode` in such cases.

```
$data = base64_decode($data);
```

This line is probably causing the issues in this, since the data is not used as a data url but saved to a file directly.

Comment: also `list(, $base64) = explode(",",$img,2);` would work for isolating the data

Comment: There is a comment regarding the str_replace on PHP.net: "If you want to save data that is derived from a Javascript canvas.toDataURL() function, you have to convert blanks into plusses. If you do not do that, the decoded data is corrupted:
".

http://no1.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: @EirikHoem Thanks for that comment! Very useful. I will update my answer and refer to the link...